Distinguishing between proof by smallest counter example and induction
I am currently learning basic proof techniques and the textbook I am using introduced proof by induction and smallest counterexample as the two separate techniques. The following summarizes how the textbook describes each approach:
Induction:

Establish truth for a base case; the number of base cases will (in my own words) depend on how far back one must reach to prove the inductive hypothesis. If the inductive hypothesis to prove $P(n + 1)$ only requires knowing that $P(n)$ is true, we only need one base case, since only the first statement in our sequence lacks the neccesary preceding statement. However, if the inductive hypothesis to prove $P(n + 1)$ requires knowing that $P(n - 3)$ is true, then we would need four base cases since the first four numbers in our sequence of statements do not have the necessary preceding statement that is four values behind them.
Inductive hypothesis; assume that $P(j)$ is true for some or multiple $j <= n$ and show that $P(n + 1)$ is true. The textbook sort of distinguishes between two types of induction based on the inductive hypothesis. Either we assume $P(n)$ is true and show $P(n + 1)$ (standard induction) or we assume $P(j)$ for all $j <= n$ and show $P(n + 1)$ (strong induction). In reality, I believe this categorization to be misleading for learning purposes. In the latter case of strong induction, most examples assume $P(j)$ for all $j <= n$ but only use a handful of these assumed statements in the proof. In my opinion, one should understand induction as assuming the truth of a few preceding statements and showing that you can then show the truth of a subsequent statement; the base cases cover the statements that do not have the preceding statement needed in the inductive hypothesis.

Proof by Smallest Counterexample:

Establish truth for the base cases. The base case covers the fact that the contradiction will assume the truth of at least one preceding statement, so we must prove that statements that do not have these necessary preceding statements are true.
Assume the overall statement is untrue and establish contradiction. Assuming the overall statement is untrue just means there exists at least one statement $S(n)$ that does not hold. Our base cases will guarantee that there exists a statement that does not hold but does possess the relevant preceding statements that do hold. From the relevant preceding statement(s) that does/do hold, we can prove that the statement of interest does hold, thereby establishing a contradiction.

I write all of this to say that proof by smallest counterexample just seems like proof by induction, but instead of proving the inductive hypothesis directly, we use proof by contradiction. As such, is it worth even distinguishing the two? My textbook seems to verify this conclusion, given that all problems labeled as "induction" just provide direct proofs for the inductive hypothesis.

Proof vy smallest counterexample is an indirect proof, using the fact that the natural numbers are "well-ordered." This fact turns out to be equivalent to induction. Smallest counterexample is more similar to so-called "strong induction" proofs, but strong induction follows so easily from simple induction, I don't think of it as that big a difference.

Personally, I've never heard the name "smallest counterexample proof." I've always heard this called a "well-ordering proof."

Well-ordering proof (which if we are trying to prove a statement is true is a proof by contradiction by proving there can't be a smallest counterexample) can follow direction as a proof by induction.  Let $w$ be the index of any counter example. Let $Q(n)$ be the statement "If $n\le w$ then $P(w-n)$ is false"  If you can prove the inductions step the by induction we will have prove $P(0)=P(w-w)$ is false but we show it is true.  A contradiction so there is no $w$ where $P(w)$ is false.
